# Issue is clicking web-element in a table in qtp

Tags: automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I have a question in UFT 12.

My scenario is:
1. Type text in a WebEdit. Say "GOOG"
2. When I type "GOOG" slowly, it lists out the symbols that start with "G". From this list out, I want to select the first element.
3. Once I click on the first element, the Google quotes are displayed.

My Issue:
UFT just types GOOG and doesn't show me the list that lays out for me to select the first element that starts with "G".

From the Object spy, I managed to find the first element as a web element.

I tried many different ways like childitem etc. Nothing seems to work. Please help me out.

I am not able to attach my screen shot here. This is something similar to Google suggest where you type and it suggests you so many options and go with the first option.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to automate auto-complete textbox. So you should not directly paste the string value in the textbox as we used to do for normal edit controls, instead you should split the string into separate characters and type one by one.

If if you do in such a way, then the AUT will list the matching options to pick. From there you can select the required option. Then you may use SendKeys method (** something like Down Arrow + Enter) to pick the selection.

Just a have attempt in this way - good luck!

Comment: Alternatively, googling Mercury.DeviceReplay shows a second option for emulating keyboard input 1:1 (as apposed to .Set, which does not exactly behave like keyboard input).

Comment: You can also use WScript.SendKeys method to emulate the behaviour